# How to return NaN if ArrayList is empty

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am doing a Java practice which is asking me to return the average of a list of numbers. And if the arrayList is empty, NaN is returned.

```
public class ListAverage {
    public static double findAverageDouble(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
        if(numbers.size() != 0) {
            numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
            
            double sum = 0.0;
            
            for(double num : numbers){
                sum += num;
            }
            
            double average = (sum / numbers.size());
            
            return average;
        } else {
            return NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure that my first part(finding the average) is correct. But how can return NaN? Thanks for any help!

---

Edit: After I return Double.NaN.
I got this error, in which all test cases return NaN.
[image]

Comment: there is no NaN in java. Null can be returrned

Comment: @leoOrion A Java double respects the IEEE specification, so it can hold the value NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no NaN itself in Java, but there are constants `Double.NaN` and `Float.NaN`. Return one of them.

[Java NaN](https://www.baeldung.com/java-not-a-number)

Also you can reduce nesting of your code

```
public static double findAverageDouble(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
    if(numbers.size() == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
        
    double sum = 0.0;
        
    for(double num : numbers) {
        sum += num;
    }
        
    double average = (sum / numbers.size());
        
    return average;
}
```

Update:
In line

```
numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

you overwrite the list losing values, so answer for non empty list will always be 0. Remove this line.

Comment: I don't understand the error I have using my code and also yours. Could you please help? I have edited my post

Comment: @HY2000 If you are stilling having the error, we need a [mre] to help you with it, please.

Answer (score 2):

### Stream solution

It may not be what you are after, perhaps if this was for an exercise. Averaging a list of double numbers is built-in, or almost.

```
public static double findAverageDouble(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
    return numbers.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
            .average()
            .orElse(Double.NaN);
}
```

`DoubleStream.average()` returns an `OptionalDouble`, and you may consider returning that directly rather than NaN. In the code above I took your word for it and used `orElse()` to pick NaN for return value in case of an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for posting the `Stream`-based solution. Anyone (including the OP) serious about a career in Java technology must learn and use `Stream` API wherever appropriate.